# how to Swing the stack object?

Tags: iphone, chipmunk

I want to stack the objects like scoop game for iPhone & Tower Bloxx. I want to move that stack to left & right based on accelerometer. I am trying to do it by using chipmunk. I am able to stack but I cant able to swing that stack when it's moving from left to right or vice versa.

If anyone knows it please help me out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "but I cant able to swing that stack when it's moving from left to right". Do you mean you want it to fall over/tumble? Or you want it to slide yet stay together?

Answer (score 0):

You might try asking over at:

http://iphonegamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: That site isn't frequented as much as stackoverflow, unfortunately.

Comment: Well if people don't ask questions there it never will be!

I have no involvement with the site beyond the fact I think it's a really good idea to have that specialization.